# Can you block the sidewalk in front of your house in a gated community?

Tags: florida, hoa

We been getting window stickers in a gated community about parking on our driveway and partly blocking sidewalks. Is it legal or not?

Comment: A gated community is likely to have a Home Owners Association (HOA) that has its own unique set of rules that would layer on top of Florida's laws. Are the window stickers being left by an HOA, or the police?

Answer (score 7):

Gated communities are generally part of homeowner's associations that have covenants, rules and regulations regarding how you can use your property. In all likelihood, blocking sidewalk, and perhaps even parking in your driveway, is prohibited by these HOA limitations.

HOA's have the right to ticket and fine you for violating its rules. The fines, if not paid, can be converted to liens and used to foreclose upon your property. You can also be banned from using HOA common areas if you do not refrain from violating HOA rules and/or don't pay your fines.

This is perfectly legal. If you live in gated community, you are required to follow their rules.

Even if you didn't live in an HOA, blocking a sidewalk is usually a violation of municipal ordinances and is tortious activity that can be the basis for a lawsuit against you.